# In how many possible ways can we write $3240$ as a product of $3$ positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many possible ways can we write $3240$ as a product of $3$ positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$?

This is the question where I've been stuck. The answer is $450$, but I don't know why. I've tried taking out the number of factors, then applying the combination formula in different ways.

Comment: Is $a,b,c$ can be equal or $a\neq b\neq c$?

Comment: check:http://www.logicguns.com/q/in-how-many-possible-ways-can-write-3240-as-a-product-of-3-positive-integers-ab-and-c/565b4db32b78724573b3ead8/

Comment: There is no such conditions

Comment: What @NoChance, posted, visit there. you will get the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$3240=2^3\cdot3^4\cdot5^1$$

---

The factor $2$ can be split among $3$ divisors in $10$ different ways:

- $0,0,3$
- $0,1,2$
- $0,2,1$
- $0,3,0$
- $1,0,2$
- $1,1,1$
- $1,2,0$
- $2,0,1$
- $2,1,0$
- $3,0,0$

---

The factor $3$ can be split among $3$ divisors in $15$ different ways:

- $0,0,4$
- $0,1,3$
- $0,2,2$
- $0,3,1$
- $0,4,0$
- $1,0,3$
- $1,1,2$
- $1,2,1$
- $1,3,0$
- $2,0,2$
- $2,1,1$
- $2,2,0$
- $3,0,1$
- $3,1,0$
- $4,0,0$

---

The factor $5$ can be split among $3$ divisors in $3$ different ways:

- $0,0,1$
- $0,1,0$
- $1,0,0$

---

Hence the total number of ways to write it as a product of $3$ divisors is $10\cdot15\cdot3=450$.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: Haha, thanks :)

Comment: @Harshvardhan: Your welcome, feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Answer (score 3):

Express $3240$ as a factors of prime numbers

$$3240 = 2\times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 5 = 2^{3} \times 3^{4} \times 5^{1}$$

so these $3$ numbers of $2$'s can be distributed to $3$ integres $a,b,c$ in :

$$\binom{3+(3-1)}{3-1} \text{ ways i.e. } \binom52=10 \text{ ways}$$

Numbers of ways in which $4$ numbers of $3$'s can be distributed to $3$ integers :

$$\binom{4+(3-1)}{3-1} \text{ ways i.e. } \binom62=15 \text{ ways}$$

Numbers of ways in which $1$ number of $5$ can be distributed to $3$ integers :

$$\binom{1+(3-1)}{3-1} \text{ ways i.e. } \binom32=3 \text{ ways}$$

So total ways $= 10 \times 15 \times 3 = 450$

Answer (score 2):

Since $3240$ has prime factorization $3240 = 2^33^45^1$, each positive integer factor of $3240$ has the form $2^{\alpha}3^{\beta}5^{\gamma}$, where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are non-negative integers satisfying the inequalities $0 \leq \alpha \leq 3$, $0 \leq \beta \leq 4$, and $0 \leq \gamma \leq 1$.  Suppose that $3240 = abc$, where 
\begin{align*}
a & = 2^{x_1}3^{y_1}5^{z_1}\\
b & = 2^{x_2}3^{y_2}5^{z_2}\\
c & = 2^{x_3}3^{y_3}5^{z_3}
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 3 \tag{1}\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 & = 4 \tag{2}\\
z_1 + z_2 + z_3 & = 1 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equations 1, 2, and 3 are equations in the non-negative integers.

A particular solution of equation 1 corresponds to placing two addition signs in a row of three ones.  For instance,
$$+ + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0$, and $x_3 = 3$, while
$$1 + 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 1$, and $x_3 = 1$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation 1 is the number of ways two addition signs  can be inserted into a row of three ones, which is 
$$\binom{3 + 2}{2} = \binom{5}{2}$$
since we must choose which two of the five symbols (three ones and two addition signs) will be addition signs.

By similar argument, the number of solutions of equation 2 is 
$$\binom{4 + 2}{2} = \binom{6}{2}$$
and the number of solutions of equation 3 is 
$$\binom{1 + 2}{2} = \binom{3}{2}$$
Hence, the number of ways $3240$ can be expressed as the product of three positive integers is 
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{3}{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

3420 can be written as 2^3 . 3^4 . 5^1

We have 3 places _ _ _ or lets denote them as x y z.

We have to distribute 3 '2's, 6 '3's and 1 '5' into 3 places, where '2','3','5' are objects.

Now, How many ways to distribute 3 '2's ? You observe that no matter how you distribute '2's the total number of '2's will always be 3.

Lets say you distribute the '2's such that x gets 1 '2', y gets 1 '2', z gets 1 '2' like so ----- 2|2|2

The bars (|) separate what x, y, z gets like so ----------------------------------------------- x|y|z

Again you can distribute such that x gets no '2', y gets 2 '2's, z gets 1 '2' like ----------- |2.2|2

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- x| y |z

Again you can distribute such that x gets 3 '2's, y gets no '2', z gets no '2' like --------- 2.2.2||

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- x|y|z

Therefore you see this is an arrangement problem of 5 items with 3 similar items (3 '2's) and 2 similar items (2 bars(|))

Therefore no. of ways to distribute 3 '2's to 3 places will be 5!/(3! . 2!) = 10 ways

Similarly for distributing 4 '3's to 3 places will be arranging ||3.3.3.3 ; which is 6!/(4! . 2!) = 15 ways.

No. of was to distribute 1 '5' to 3 places is 3 ways

Therefore the total no. of ways is 10.15.3 = 450 ways.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Comment: Thank you for contributing. But it is generally better to focus on newer or not yet answered posts. Moreover, posts that are formatted using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) are generally better received.