# How many ways can 15000 be written as the product of 3 integers?

Tags: combinatorics, factoring

I've looked at questions similar to these, such as ([In how many possible ways can we write $3240$ as a product of $3$ positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629068/in-how-many-possible-ways-can-we-write-3240-as-a-product-of-3-positive-integ)).
I don't understand how he got 10 when he split it among 3 divisors.

The prime factorization of $15000$ is $2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^4$. 
Can anyone use this to explain to me?

Comment: Is the order of the integers significant?

Comment: @barakmanos Ex. 15000=15*10*100 and 15000=10*15*100 are different

Comment: @paw88789: Yes, that's why I have removed that part of the comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to place eggs in baskets with the bar method?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

1. Divide 3 eggs labeled '2' over 3 baskets in $5\choose{2}$ ways by placing 2 bars in 3+2 positions.
2. Divide 1 egg labeled '3' over 3 baskets, 3 ways
3. Divide 4 eggs labeled '5' over 3 baskets. $6 \choose 2$

Multiply..

Comment: So basically stars and bars?

Comment: A somewhat more creative version of it.. I think it should work.

Comment: For 2, how are there 5 bars? Can you explain?

Comment: There are 3 stars and 2 bars. You have 5 positions, and need to select 2 for the bars